# Strongloop: how do you return an error if Operation Hook fails?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

How do you return an error inside an operation hook?

Use case is sending a push notification after saving a new model instance.

I observe the `'after save'` event, send the push. If this fails for whatever reason, I want to send a `500 response` code. How do I do that?

I am unable to find documentation as to what the `ctx` object actually is or contains.

```
Customer.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {

  //model saved, but sending push failed for whatever reason, and I want to now send a 500 error back to the user
  //how?  what's inside ctx? how do you send back a response?  
  next();
});
```

Comment: You can inspect the ctx object with a `console.log(ctx)`. It is the context object that represents the request and associated data (`ctx.instance` is your Customer instance, for example). To pass errors through operation hooks, pass the error via `next(error);` as the last line in your hook. But that's where my understanding ends—I'm not sure where this ends up or how to handle it in a central place.

Comment: You can use assert module to throw errors in clean way.

Answer (score 12):

I believe it's something along these lines:

```
var error = new Error();
error.status = 500;
next(error);
```

Comment: `next(err)` returns the right object but pollute my logs with "unhandled error". I think that without `throw error` it shouldn't print that. What should I do? thanks

Answer (score 9):

Extending the previous answer, as I cannot add comments yet.

You can provide more information to the error response with:

```
var error = new Error();
error.status = 401;
error.message = 'Authorization Required';
error.code = 'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED';
```

This will return something like:

```
{
   "error": {
      "name": "Error",
      "status": 401,
      "message": "Authorization Required",
      "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
      "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n    at ..."
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed documentation on what **ctx** actually contains. It can be found in [Loopback after-save operation hook docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#after-save).

The ctx object has the `instance` method which returns the model instance that was saved. You can return the error after checking the model instance like so:

```
if (ctx.instance) {
  // check if your push operation modified the instance
  // If condition is not met, throw the error
  var error = new Error()
  error.status = 500
  error.message = '...'
  next(error)
}
```

The documentation above covers the properties of the ctx object for the `after save` hook.